# Routing on AngularJS + Kendo UI Mobile app

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-mobile, angular-kendo

I am very new to AngularJS + Kendo UI Mobile.

I am not even sure if it's supposed to be called Angular Kendo.

However, while reading through various sources, I came across conflicting statements regarding the routing mechanism of an app that uses AngularJS and Kendo UI Mobile.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction says :

`If you are using AngularJS then you probably want to use Angular's own routing mechanism and data binding. Do not mix that with Kendo MVVM.`

However this example here http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/angular/angular mentions :

`The mobile application instantiates and maintains its own routing mechanism based on the router component, which automatically matches and instantiates views when navigating. Unlike the ng-route/ng-view and the ui-router implementations, the mobile application does not unload the previous view when navigating to the new one.`

So, what should I do? Which is the most preferred way and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've incurred the same sort of conflicting info you have. Basically, it seems Telerik first put out a solution around April '14, but then modified the integration and structuring methods around November '14.

The Telerik resource linked here should be helpful to devs looking to optimally integrate AngularJS functionality into Kendo UI Mobile, as it's the post 2014 Q3 version: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/angular/sushi-angular-tutorial